# Algorithmic puzzle: Ball Stacking Problem

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve this problem: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1312

> The XYZ TV channel is developing a new game show, where a contestant
> has to make some choices in order to get a prize. The game consists of
> a triangular stack of balls, each of them having an integer value, as
> the following example shows.
>
> [image]
>
> The contestant must choose which balls he is going to take and his
> prize is the sum of the values of those balls. However, the contestant
> can take any given ball only if he also takes the balls directly on
> top of it. This may require taking additional balls using the same
> rule. Notice that the contestant may choose not to take any ball, in
> which case the prize is zero.
>
> The TV show director is concerned about
> the maximum prize a contestant can make for a given stack. Since he is
> your boss and he does not know how to answer this question, he
> assigned this task to you.
>
> #### Input
>
> Each test case is described using several lines. The first line
> contains an integer *N* representing the number of rows of the stack (1
> ≤ *N* ≤ 1000). The *i <sup>th</sup>* of the next *N* lines contains *i* integers *B<sub>ij</sub>*
> (−105 ≤ *B<sub>ij</sub>* ≤ 105 for 1 ≤ *j* ≤ *i* ≤ *N*); the number *B<sub>ij</sub>* is the value of
> the *j <sup>th</sup>* ball in the *i <sup>th</sup>* row of the stack (the first row is the
> topmost one, and within each row the first ball if the leftmost one).
>
> The last test case is followed by a line containing one zero.
>
> #### Output
>
> ```
> Sample Input  | Sample Output
> 4             |   7 
> 3             |   0
> -5 3          |   6
> -8 2 -8       |
> 3 9 -2 7      |
> 2             |
> -2            |
> 1 -10         |
> 3             |
> 1             |
> -5 3          |
> 6 -4 1        |
> 0             |
> ```

I'd love a pointer or two on how to solve this problem.

It seems like it is solvable using a DP approach, but I can't quite formulate the recurrence. The fact that two adjacent balls could have overlapping children is making things a bit difficult.

Comment: What is the output? It doesn’t explain what you’re actually trying to calculate? Is it the highest possible score?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: In case anyone is wondering why the first output is 7: Choose balls 3 and 9 from the last row, then you'll also have to get -8 and 2 from the 3rd row, -5 and 3 from the 2nd row and 3 from the 1st row. 3 + 9 - 8 + 2 - 5 + 3 + 3 = 7.

Comment: This seems very heavy to solve for large cases. With N=1000 there are 500500 balls to choose from, giving 2^500500 possible combinations. Although most of them collapse to the same configuration, there still will be too many possibilities to test (and not enough memory to store the DP). Even N=100 seems hard to tackle in general. Some tricks and some luck can help to prune away part of the possibilities, but never enough to make the problem feasible.

Comment: I was thinking that this could be treated like a path finding problem but you could potentially have 3 or more balls taken from the bottom with multiple spaces between them meaning that path finding is ruled out.

Comment: Looks like classical dynamic programming. Start at the top and work down. Linear time in the number of balls.

Comment: @Gene can you expand on your approach in an answer?

Answer (score 5):

This is DP, but we're going sideways instead of top-down. Let's tilt the ball stack a little to the left, so we can look at the whole stack as a sequence of columns.

```
 3  3 -8  7
-5  2 -2
-8  9
 3
```

From this viewpoint the rule of the game becomes: if we want to take a ball, we also need to take the ball above, and the ball directly to its left.

Now, solving the problem. We'll calculate a quantity `S[i, j]` for each ball
-- this represents the best sum we could achieve if the ball at position [i, j] is taken (the `jth ball from the top of the ith column), *while considering only the first i columns*.

I claim that the following recurrence holds (with some sensible initial conditions):

```
S[i, j] = MAX(S[i-1, j] + C[i, j], S[i, j+1])
```

where `C[i, j]` is the sum of the first j balls in the ith column.

Let's break that down a bit. We want to calculate `S[i, j]`.

- We have to take the ball at [i, j]. And let's suppose for now that this is the bottom-most ball we take from this column.
- This requires all the balls in this column above it to be taken, with the sum (including [i, j] itself) being `C[i, j]`.
- It also requires the ball at [i-1, j] to be taken (unless we're at the leftmost column, of course). We know that the best sum from taking this ball is `S[i-1, j]`, by definition.
- So the best possible total sum is: `S[i-1, j] + C[i, j]`, or just `C[i, j]` for the leftmost column.
- But we can choose differently and take more balls from this column (if we have more balls). We need to calculate and take the maximum value out of `S[i-1, j] + C[i, j]`, `S[i-1, j+1] + C[i, j+1]`, and so on, all the way down to the bottom of the pile.
  With a little induction it's easy to see this is equal to `MAX(S[i-1, j] + C[i, j], S[i, j+1])`.

The implementation should be obvious now. We process the stack column-by-column, in each column calculate the partial sum `C[i, j]` from the top down, then work out `S[i, j]` from bottom up.
Finally, just take the maximum value of `S[i, j]` we've encountered (or 0) as the answer.

This runs in linear time to the number of balls, so O(N^2).

To illustrate, here's (`C[i, j]`, `S[i, j]`) pairs for the given example.

```
(  3, 3) ( 3,7) ( -8,-1)  (7,6)
( -2,-2) ( 5,7) (-10,-3) 
(-10,-7) (14,7)
( -7,-7)
```

Answer (score 2):

(Updated with better understanding from Worakarn Isaratham's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59440151/2034787).)

We can have a naive recurrence with `O(N^2)` search space (note that there are `O(N^2)` total balls so to do any better we could not examine all entries) by iterating over the diagonals. Let's say southwest.

```
       \ jth NW diagonal
        x
       x o
      A o x
     x o x o
    x o x B x / ...etc
   C o x o x o / 3rd iteration
  x o D o E F x / 2nd iteration
 x o x o x o x o / 1st iteration (ith SW diagonal)
x o x o x o x G x
           / / / \
```

Each choice along a southwest diagonal, would restrict all the rest of the choices and sums below a northwest diagonal (e.g., being able to choose E means we've only chosen as far as the FG diagonal on previous iterations and choosing it would restrict all subsequent choices below the AE diagonal.

Say we label southwest diagonals as `i` and our northwest bound as `j`, and have a function `sum_northwest` that calculates in `O(1)` (using prefix sums) and takes as parameters one northwest diagonal and a southwest bound. Then, if `f(i, j)` represents the optimal choice up to the `i`th southwest column with nothwest bound `j`:

```
f(i, j) = max(
  // Skip choosing from
  // this southwest diagonal
  f(i - 1, j),

  // Choose this northwest diagonal
  // on this southwest diagonal
  sum_northwest(j - 1, i) + f(i - 1, j - 1),

  // Choose an earlier northwest diagonal,
  // but then we are obliged to also
  // include this northwest diagonal
  sum_northwest(j - 1, i) + f(i, j - 1)
)
```

Time complexity is `O(|I| * |J|)`, assuming we are tabling results.

JavaScript code (not optimised):

```js
function sum_northwest(M, j, i){
  return M[j].slice(0, i + 1)
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
}

function f(M, i, j){
  if (i < 0 || j < 1 || i >= M[M.length-j].length)
    return 0

  let this_northwest =
    sum_northwest(M, M.length - j, i)

  return Math.max(
    f(M, i - 1, j),
    this_northwest + f(M, i - 1, j - 1),
    this_northwest + f(M, i, j - 1)
  )
}

var M = [
  [ 3, 3,-8, 7],
  [-5, 2,-2],
  [-8, 9],
  [ 3]
]

console.log(f(M, 3, 4))

M = [
  [-2,-10],
  [ 1]
]

console.log(f(M, 1, 2))

M = [
  [ 1, 3, 1],
  [-5,-4],
  [ 6]
]

console.log(f(M, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     O
    /\
   /  \
 A/    \B
 / \  / \
/   \/   \
C    M    D
```

Suppose we take a ball at M, then we also need to take all the balls from the region MAOB. We are left with 2 triangles: CAM and MBD, and we need to select balls from these two triangles to maximize the points. This is the same problem, but with a smaller input.
So we define the value function over the sets of all sub-triangles in the stack

Let `C[i,j,h]` = maximum points from a sub-triangle with the top at `(i,j)` and with height = `h` (I use right-angled triangles to illustrate here because it is easier to draw)

```
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
| A  \
| |\  \
| | \  \
| |  \  \
| |D  \E \
| |\  |\  \
| | \ | \  \
| |__\|__\  \
| B   M   C  \
|_____________\

A = (i,j) 
B = (i+h, j)
C = (i+h, j+h)
M = (i+h, j+k)
D = (i, j+h-k)
E = (i+k, j+k)
```

Recursive formula:

```
C[i,j,h] = max(
   C[i,j,h-1] // pick no ball at line i+h
   C[i,j+h-k,k] + C[i+k,j+k,h-k] + sum(ADME) for k from 0 to h // if pick a ball at (i+h, j+k)
)
```

Comment: I think it's really close, just that you may pick more than one ball from each line and your recursive formula does not really address that.

Comment: Please also add a time complexity and a running example over the given example. I think it will really improve your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I will show a solution in `O(N log N)` time complexity and `O(N)` memory complexity.

First of all, you are correct we will use a Dynamic Programing approach. The data structure we will use will be a triangle of the same size. Each ball in the new triangle will be the value of the competitor if it took that ball. We can build it in `O(N)` time - top to bottom.

Now we need to notice some interesting claim: The ball with the highest value in the new triangle will be taken (unless it's negative in which case we will not take any thing).
Proof: (Quite straightforward) If not taken, than we can take it and necessarily get the total value higher.

Another interesting claim: All the balls below (that will take it if they were taken) the the ball with highest score in the data structure - will not be taken.
Proof: If they were taken it mean that the value of them is positive without the ball with the highest value and that means that their value is higher which is impossible.

Now to the algorithm:

```
Build the data structure.
Set of all taken items = {}
while there are positive elements in the structure:
    Take highest one - put in the set.
    make all below it 0, and put then in the set.
    make all above it negative infinity.
    Rebuild the data structure for the rest.
Return the set
```

This will always be optimal - we take the ball with highest value, we will never miss a ball that ban help us, and we will never miss other balls since we rebuild the data structure.

Memory complexity is simple: `O(N)` for the data structure.
Time complexity is tricky: Creating the data structure is `O(N)`, each time in the loop we remove at least half of the elements and we will not recompute for them, therefore number of iterations will be logarithmic in `N` so `O(N log N)`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Could you please show an example with a very small input?

Comment: Also, I don't see how O(N log N) is possible when there are O(N^2) balls according to the question description.

Comment: Correct, I addressed N as number of balls, I guess it's just O(N^2 log N)